# Bullets not working in Bootstrap Dropdown Menus Enhancement plugin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I use [Bootstrap Dropdown Menus Enhancement](http://behigh.github.io/bootstrap_dropdowns_enhancement/) to center dropdown-menus and have bullet between my button and the actual menu. The centering part works just fine, but the bullet is absent if I have another class, which is the following:

```
.scrollable-menu 
{
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

The class used to have bullets (part of the library) is the following:

```
.dropdown-menu.bullet {
   margin-top: 8px;
}
.dropdown-menu.bullet:before {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   border-color: transparent;
   border-style: solid;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
   border-width: 0 7px 7px;
   border-bottom-color: #cccccc;
   border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
   top: -7px;
   left: 9px;
}
.dropdown-menu.bullet:after {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   border-color: transparent;
   border-style: solid;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
   border-width: 0 6px 6px;
   border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
   top: -6px;
   left: 10px;
}
```

Here's the HTML in question:

```
<div class="btn-group" id="station_btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Station <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu bullet pull-center" id="station_list" role="menu">
        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header text-left"><b>Corridor: </b></li>
        <!-- Append list dynamically -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's how it looks how with .scrollable-menu:

[image: screencap1]

and without .scrollable-menu:

[image: screencap2]

How can I have the same scrollable-menu display, but also have the bullet?

Comment: your html would be helpful, as would a demo on jsfiddle or similar.

Comment: I've added the HTML in question

Comment: that html lacks the `.scrollable-menu` class.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to replace it after the screencaps. It's there now.

Comment: it's hard to say what's overriding the `.scrollable-menu.bullet` styling without a live example to inspect. you could set one up on jsfiddle and probably get a better response. have you tested changing the `top: -7px` to another value? the bullet could be getting nudged under the menu and just not be visible or something.

Comment: I've changed the value, but no result. I've never used jsfiddle before.

Comment: you can inspect the DOM with developer tools, find the `:before` and `:after` stuff in the inspection window, and then test adding / altering different properties. do this until you get the bullet to appear, and then you'll have found your answer

Comment: the overflow-x: hidden is the problem.